# Way to stop unwanted items being printed to screen with Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

When you run a Scrapy program, either from Python Shell or Command Line, you get items printed to the screen such as the following:

```
c:\Python27\webscraper2\webscraper2>scrapy crawl mrcrawl2
2014-08-28 00:12:21+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.4 started (bot: webscraper2)
2014-08-28 00:12:21+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2014-08-28 00:12:21+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'webscraper2.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['webscraper2.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'webscraper2'}
2014-08-28 00:12:21+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-08-28 00:12:21+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddle
ware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-08-28 00:12:21+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-08-28 00:12:21+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2014-08-28 00:12:21+0100 [mrcrawl2] INFO: Spider opened
2014-08-28 00:12:21+0100 [mrcrawl2] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-08-28 00:12:21+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2014-08-28 00:12:21+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2014-08-28 00:12:21+0100 [mrcrawl2] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.whoscored.com> (referer: None)
```

Is there a way to disable things being printed to screen that have not been scraped from a web page? Ideally I only want the 'DEBUG: Crawled' line to print to screen if the response is not within the range 200-300.

I have tried looking on Google for an answer, but I'm not really sure what to search for.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `-L WARNING` option to set loglevel to `WARNING`:

```
scrapy crawl mrcrawl2 -L WARNING
```

It'll print message only when something goes wrong.

Comment: Can you help me find the `-L WARNING` in src code?... I can't find it under crawl command `https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/tree/master/scrapy/commands`

Comment: @B.Mr.W. please take a look at: https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/command.py#L88

Comment: @kev This -L option is awesome. Otherwise there is too much ouput. Another question, i just want to stop the "yielded" items from printing. So i want to see everything except what is being yielded. Cause those items are usually large and take up too much space on the console.